# Image path not working

Tags: image, zend-framework

I am using Zend, and I have a folder in my `/public` called `/profile/`. I store the profile pictures in it. Say there is a file called `/test.png` inside this. I try to load the picture using

```
<?php
$path = APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/profile/test.png';
echo '<img src="' . $path . '" />';
?>
```

However, nothing loads! I copy the code and paste it in the URL, and this works fine and does show the image! What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually much simpler:

You always need a vhost to make this work. It usually points to folder

```
your-application/public
```

If your image is located:

```
your-application/public/profile/test.png
```

you then specify image path:

```
<img src="/profile/test.png" />
```

There should be no need to employ PHP in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't think of this!

Comment: What if I still wanted to use the path? I want to store my images in a /data/ folder rather than the public folder.

Comment: Because your vhost points to /public only files under that directory are accessible to the browser. Anything else, parent directory, other directories are not accessible unless you will create another vhost.

Answer (score 0):

`APPLICATION_PATH` is not HTTP but local filesystem path. You want URL rather than path.

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/profile/test.png';

echo sprintf('<img alt="" src="%s" />', $url);
```